# Polymer + dart2js: too large output

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using dart2js (via pubspec) and a simple example  has too large output in build (folder) generated,  11.4MB.

For example, I'm using a code only the `paper-input` element, but the content in `build folder` has various polymer elements.

Is there anything specific that needs to be done to produce small code?

Following the code examples (default in Webstorms):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/google/stagehand">
  <title>untitled12</title>

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Web Starter Kit">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">

  <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

  <!-- example of using a paper element -->
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/roboto.html">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body unresolved>

  <main-app></main-app>

  <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main_app.html**

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <paper-input label="Type something..." value="{{text}}"></paper-input>
    <p>
      Text: <span>{{text}}</span><br />
      Reversed: <span>{{reverseText(text)}}</span>
    </p>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

**main_app.dart**

```
@HtmlImport('main_app.html')
library untitled12.lib.main_app;

import 'dart:html';

import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_input.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart';

/// Uses [PaperInput]
@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  @property
  String text;

  /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  @reflectable
  String reverseText(String text) {
    return text.split('').reversed.join('');
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: 'untitled12'
version: 0.0.1
description: A web app built using polymer.dart.
#author: Your Name <email@example.com>
#homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.9.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.1
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.2
  reflectable: ^0.3.1
  web_components: ^0.12.0

transformers:
- web_components:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart
- $dart2js:
    $include: '**/*.bootstrap.initialize.dart'
    minify: true
    commandLineOptions:
    - --trust-type-annotations
    - --trust-primitives
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because of the `polymer_elements` package. Only dart files can be treeshaken today so all the html and js files from that package will appear in the build output. Your actual app will not be this big though when accessed by users, so it is typically not an issue.

Basically the limiting factor today is that the way transformers work, only a transformer in the `polymer_elements` package could delete files during build. However that transformer would not have access to your application to figure out which files are actually being used.

The only real solution today is to have your own separate build step which deletes unnecessary files, but that is rarely worth the effort.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I am more relaxed in knowing what is normal behavior today!